# Android broadcast receiver not running Service on RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an Android app that uses the pedometer. Currently having trouble getting the service to start up when the user restarts/turns their phone on and off. I am using 5.1, and testing has been done on a simulator. I am not sure if it is working since the logs have not been appearing in the console.

Any help is much appreciated!

App Manifest Class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="app.apphub.devon.walkingquest">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WalkingQuestSplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filtering>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filtering>

    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".StepCounterSensorRegister" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Boot Receiver Class:
    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Log.i("BROADCAST", "WALKING_QUEST_BOOT");
        Intent _intent = new Intent("app.apphub.devon.walkingquest.StepCounterSensorRegister");
        intent.setClass(context, StepCounterSensorRegister.class);
        context.startService(_intent);
        //context.startService(_intent);
        //Toast.makeText(context,"Airplane mode on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Log.i("FAIL","BROADCAST FAILED");
    }
}
```

StepCounterSensorRegister Class:

```
public class StepCounterSensorRegister extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;
long globalSteps;
boolean flag = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(){

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Must run in background thread
    Log.i("START","STEP_COUNTER_STARTED");
    registerSensor(sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(!flag){

    }
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER){
        Log.i("STEPS DETECTED",""+globalSteps);
        globalSteps++;
    }
}

public boolean registerSensor(int accuracy) {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    try {
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }

    if(sensor == null) {
        Log.i("FAILED","Sensor returned null");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Log.i("SUCCESS", "Successfully registered sensor");
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, accuracy);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I see is that you declared something wrong in your manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filtering>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filtering>

    </receiver>
```

1. `intent-filtering`  doesn´t exist, it is `intent-filter`
2. the permissions `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` is misplaced here, don´t put it inside receiver tag. You have already defined it above.

And be sure you set the correct filter in your Logcat, you are using two different tags "BROADCAST" and "FAIL", maybe also this is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! removing the extra permission, and fixing intent-filter worked for me.